# How do i play an HLS stream when playlist.m3u8 file is constantly being updated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, vlc, http-live-streaming

I am using MediaRecorder to record chunks of my live video in webm format from MediaStream and converting these chunks to .ts files on the server using ffmpeg and then updating my playlist.m3u8 file with this code:

```
function generateM3u8Playlist(fileDataArr, playlistFp, isLive, cb) {
    var durations = fileDataArr.map(function(fd) {
        return fd.duration;
    });
    var maxT = maxOfArr(durations);

    var meta = [
        '#EXTM3U',
        '#EXT-X-VERSION:3',
        '#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0',
        '#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES',
        '#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:' + Math.ceil(maxT),
    ];

    fileDataArr.forEach(function(fd) {
        meta.push('#EXTINF:' + fd.duration.toFixed(2) + ',');
        meta.push(fd.fileName2);
    });

    if (!isLive) {
        meta.push('#EXT-X-ENDLIST');
    }

    meta.push('');
    meta = meta.join('\n');

    fs.writeFile(playlistFp, meta, cb);
}
```

Here `fileDataArr` holds information for all the chunks that have been created.

After that i use this code to create a hls server :

```
var runStreamServer = (function(streamFolder) {
    var executed = false;
    return function(streamFolder) {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            var HLSServer = require('hls-server')
            var http = require('http')

            var server = http.createServer()
            var hls = new HLSServer(server, {
                path: '/stream', // Base URI to output HLS streams
                dir: 'C:\\Users\\Work\\Desktop\\live-stream\\webcam2hls\\videos\\' + streamFolder // Directory that input files are stored
            })
            console.log("We are going to stream from folder:" + streamFolder);
            server.listen(8000);
            console.log('Server Listening on Port 8000');
        }
    };
})();
```

The problem is that if i stop creating new chunks and then use the hls server link:
`http://localhost:8000/stream/playlist.m3u8` then the video plays in VLC but if i try to play during the recording it keeps loading the file but does not play. I want it to play while its creating new chunks and updating playlist.m3u8. The quirk in `generateM3u8Playlist` function is that it adds `'#EXT-X-ENDLIST'` to the playlist file after i have stopped recording.
The software is still in production so its a bit messy code. Thank you for any answers.

The client side that generates blobs is as follows:

```
var mediaConstraints = {
            video: true,
            audio:true
        };
navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);
function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
            console.log('will start capturing and sending ' + (DT / 1000) + 's videos when you press start');
            var mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);

            mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'video/webm';

            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(blob) {
                var count2 = zeroPad(count, 5);
                // here count2 just creates a blob number 
                console.log('sending chunk ' + name + ' #' + count2 + '...');
                send('/chunk/' + name + '/' + count2 + (stopped ? '/finish' : ''), blob);
                ++count;
            };
        }
// Here we have the send function which sends our blob to server:
        function send(url, blob) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);

            xhr.responseType = 'text/plain';
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'video/webm');
            //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", blob.length);

            xhr.onload = function(e) {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    console.log(this.response);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(blob);
        }
```

The code that receives the XHR request is as follows:

```
var parts = u.split('/');
        var prefix = parts[2];
        var num = parts[3];
        var isFirst = false;
        var isLast = !!parts[4];

        if ((/^0+$/).test(num)) {
            var path = require('path');
            shell.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'videos', prefix));
            isFirst = true;
        }

        var fp = 'videos/' + prefix + '/' + num + '.webm';
        var msg = 'got ' + fp;
        console.log(msg);
        console.log('isFirst:%s, isLast:%s', isFirst, isLast);

        var stream = fs.createWriteStream(fp, { encoding: 'binary' });
        /*stream.on('end', function() {
            respond(res, ['text/plain', msg]);
        });*/

        //req.setEncoding('binary');

        req.pipe(stream);
        req.on('end', function() {
            respond(res, ['text/plain', msg]);

            if (!LIVE) { return; }

            var duration = 20;
            var fd = {
                fileName: num + '.webm',
                filePath: fp,
                duration: duration
            };
            var fileDataArr;
            if (isFirst) {
                fileDataArr = [];
                fileDataArrs[prefix] = fileDataArr;
            } else {
                var fileDataArr = fileDataArrs[prefix];
            }
            try {
                fileDataArr.push(fd);
            } catch (err) {
                fileDataArr = [];
                console.log(err.message);
            }
            videoUtils.computeStartTimes(fileDataArr);

            videoUtils.webm2Mpegts(fd, function(err, mpegtsFp) {
                if (err) { return console.error(err); }
                console.log('created %s', mpegtsFp);

                var playlistFp = 'videos/' + prefix + '/playlist.m3u8';

                var fileDataArr2 = (isLast ? fileDataArr : lastN(fileDataArr, PREV_ITEMS_IN_LIVE));

                var action = (isFirst ? 'created' : (isLast ? 'finished' : 'updated'));

                videoUtils.generateM3u8Playlist(fileDataArr2, playlistFp, !isLast, function(err) {
                    console.log('playlist %s %s', playlistFp, (err ? err.toString() : action));
                });
            });


            runStreamServer(prefix);
        }
```

Comment: The code to generate the playlist looks alright. Do fragments only get added to `fileDataArr` or also removed (i.e. is it a sliding live window or growing)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us how you use `MediaRecorder` to generate your "chunks" of data. Do you you use [its `ondataavailable` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) for this purpose?

If so, please keep this in mind: You must concatenate all the chunks handed to you by `ondataavailable` to get a valid .webm (or .matroska) data stream.

You can't just store an arbitrary chunk of data in a media file and expect it to play. Even ffmpeg needs all your chunks streamed to it to generate valid output. That's because the first couple of chunks contain the [mandatory .webm initialization segment](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#init-segment), and the other chunks do not.

Comment: Hi Jones, I have added supporting code and you are right i am using ondataavailable event to create blobs/ chunks. The solution didn't seem feasible so i am not using it anymore however if there is any workaround, please provide it with code.

Comment: I have succeeded at a similar project by opening a websocket and using it to send each chunk to the server. My application is different enough  from yours that I don't have any useful source code for you, sorry.

Comment: I am currently using websockets and kurento and have successfully created an rtmp stream but im still looking for a solution to create an HLS stream. Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: @AdnanAhmed I am trying to solve the similar problem of uploading the chunks from the Media Recorder to the server and streaming it on the web client using HLS library.

Comment: Which approach did you use finally? Can you share your insights and code?

Comment: @rbansal I used kurento to create an RTMP stream from webrtc and then use ffmpeg to convert it into HLS. It worked but there was a delay of about 5-10 seconds because of the conversion and ffmpeg isn't very reliable (atleast for me at that time). The following is the last approach i settled on: I used WebRTC to stream the video and then encoded it to RTMP by gstreamer and finally used owncast to encode it to HLS. I tried owncast with RTMP stream from kurento and it works great however gstreamer is more fast. Check out these links:

Comment: https://github.com/godka/kurento-rtmp https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtmp/index.html https://github.com/owncast/owncast

Comment: @rbansal Btw this approach in the post is very bad and fails to create a high quality and reliable stream. I recommend not using it.

Comment: @AdnanAhmed Would you please write your solution as an answer to your question?

Comment: sure. I would also appreciate if later on @rbansal edits the answer to include more details such as code etc.